# Waterfall Chart PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, waterfall

I am trying to created something like this in powerbi but nothing seems to work.

[Sample of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaJhY.png)

Data is below;

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auX6o.png)
Descrption  Original    Save    Spend
2020 Targets     64.0
2021 Target  58.8
Train 1  58.8       3.8
Train 2  62.6       2.0
Train 3  64.6       1.1
Train 4  65.7       1.0
Train 5  66.7       1.0
Train 6  67.7       0.4
Train 7  68.1       0.5
Train 8  68.6       4.1
Option 1     72.8
Train 9  69.9   2.9
Train 10     67.3   2.6
Train 11     64.7   2.6
Train 12     63.6   1.1
Train 13     63.1   0.5
Train 14     62.9   0.2
Option 2     62.9
Train 3  61.8   1.1
Train 4  60.8   1.0
Train 5  59.8   1.0
Train 6  59.4   0.4
Train 7  58.9   0.5
Option 3     58.9
2022 Targets     62.4       4.00

is there a specific DAX code that i need to write out or just need to follow different steps when entering the data in powerbi visuals

---

@Sia below is an image of what I am getting by using exact same DAX code.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4EJV.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the standard waterfall visual can suit your needs as there are several total bars.

Hereby one suggestion is that you can try "stacked column chart" visual:

*You will need calculate two new columns:*

- one is assist column, you can set it as white color. the DAX would be:

  Column Assist = SWITCH(TRUE(),
  SEARCH("Train",[Description],1,0)>0,[Original],0)

*set assist column as white color:*
[image]

- the second is value column, but i am afraid you cannot change the color . the DAX would be:

  Column Value = SWITCH(TRUE(),
  SEARCH("Train",[Description],1,0)=0,[Original],
  ISBLANK([Save]),[Spend],[Save])

Comment: Thanks @Sia. This approach works but I think the Column Value excludes the savings.  I have applied and all the Spend amounts are missing from the chart. I think formula is incomplete.

Comment: After Train 9 the saving shows. I only input 3 spend of Train 1-3 and 3 savings of Train 9-11 cause there are so many values.